# CSS - Maintaining hover state and delaying transitions

Tags: css, hover, transition

I'm trying to create a transition effect on a `<a>` tag within a list, which will make a nested list display. This is fine, except that I want it to coincide with a transition effect on the `<a>`, which lasts 0.5 sec. Despite trying with transition delays, it always seems to transition straight away. Basically, I want a 0.5 sec delay before the nested list appears.

I also want it so that when a user hovers over an item in the nested list, the `<a>` element still maintains it's hover state. Is this possible?

I wanted to try and do as much as possible in pure CSS.

Can anybody give me any guidance? I hope I've explained it well enough.

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WKfuW/1/

Please excuse the weird characters - I'm using @font-face for icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WKfuW/2/

I was able to achieve the goal you want by, instead of transitioning display, I transition opacity.  Display is a toggle -- it's either on or off.  But opacity is a range, from 0 to 1.  So by using that instead, I was able to delay it, fade it, and do the same in reverse.

The useful CSS is:

```
.option-list ul li ul
{
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;

    transition:opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.option-list ul li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;

    transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Easy change! Thank you. Do you have any idea how I can keep the hover state of the `.option-list ul li a` when I'm hovering over `.option-list ul li ul li a`?

Comment: By your DOM specifications, when you hover over the menu, you're no longer hovering over the `a` so no, there's no way to force the hover to stick.  However you still are hovering over the parent `li`!  So using that, changing your `.option-list ul li a:hover` rule (line 26) to `.option-list ul li:hover > a` so that you're now targeting the li on hover and targeting its direct children anchors, then it will stay highlighted through the duration of the hover event.  http://jsfiddle.net/WKfuW/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works a charm!